# Microsoft Privacy API, create SubjectRequest 403 UnknownError

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, privacy

I am trying to create [Subject Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subjectrightsrequest-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=go) (for privacy/compliance).

I am using a MS OAuth app to generate a token with scope = `SubjectRightsRequest.ReadWrite.All`,
I am able to generate the OAuth token and `GET` list of all subject requests

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/privacy/subjectRightsRequests
Content-Type: application/json

200 OK
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#privacy/subjectRightsRequests",
    "value": []
}
```

But getting `403` and `message=UnkownError` when creating a Subject Request

Example Request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/privacy/subjectRightsRequests
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "type": "delete",
    "dataSubjectType": "currentEmployee",
    "regulations": ["CCPA"],
    "displayName": "TestDSR",
    "description": "DSR for test@suhail.lol",
    "internalDueDateTime": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
    "dataSubject": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dataSubject",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User",
        "email": "test@suhail.lol",
        "residency": "CA"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-04-30T01:00:09",
            "request-id": "bb30c902-c8b9-4688-80e5-23c2272a77fb",
            "client-request-id": "bb30c902-c8b9-4688-80e5-23c2272a77fb"
        }
    }
}
```

My OAuth token response even has granted permissions for `SubjectRightsRequest.ReadWrite.All`

[image]

OAUTH Token Generation

I created the token by:

1. Create OAuth app Azure Active Directory > App Registrations

   a. Get <OAUTH_CLIENT_ID>, <OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET> and

   <OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL>
2. Then make the OAUTH use

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<OAUTH_CLIENT_ID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL>
&response_mode=query
&scope=SubjectRightsRequest.ReadWrite.All
&state=12345
```

4. Redirected to Login page. Login with Admin Account of Office 365 account
5. Redirected to <OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL>?code=<OAUTH_CODE>&state=12345
6. Exchange Token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 

Request body
grant_type=authorization_code 
code=<OAUTH_CODE>
redirect_uri=<OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL>
client_id=<OAUTH_CLIENT_ID>
client_secret=<OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET>
```

Comment: Can you explain how did you create the token? Did you login with the same credentials and got the token?

Comment: See edit in question. Thanks!

Comment: According this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/16613 probably creating delete request type is not supported.

Comment: Thank You! Been scratching my head for a while if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in **Microsoft Graph Explorer**. I have granted **`SubjectRightsRequest.Read.All`** and **`SubjectRightsRequest.ReadWrite.All`** permissions.

At first, I tried to **get the list** of all subject requests and got the response below:

[image]

Now, I tried to **create delete request type** for subjectRightsRequest by posting query like below and got same error:

[image]

***As mentioned by*** **[@user2250152](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250152/user2250152)**, ***creating delete request type for subjectRightsRequest is currently may not be supported.***

To resolve the above error, try to raise the **[support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/)** to Microsoft.